# Django CMS 3.5.2 Internalization - translate template text

Tags: django, internationalization, django-cms

I have a couple of questions about Django CMS 3.5.2 translation.

1) My website is in three languages. I want to translate my template text into all three languages. I have tried using the `{% trans 'my text' %}` tag, but, when I write the `python manage.py makemessages -l all` command, my terminal indicates the following error message instead of creating a .po file:

```
    RuntimeWarning,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 7, in <module>
    startup.manage(path=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aldryn_django/startup.py", line 12, in manage
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named deconstruct
```

I am just wondering if there's another way to translate texts in Django CMS.

2) Is there a way to add the option to translate texts for non-developers? 
Something like the following (but not only for page names):
[image]
Thank you!

Comment: So does your settings file have `deconstruct` in it? Does the `runserver` work? This looks like something that'd stop everything from running. Also you can get programs which read the translation files so that non-devs can provide the translations through a gui.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the message. Do you know what should I put in the deconstruct module? I am new to python/Django.

Comment: Hang on, does `deconstruct` get imported to your settings? I've no idea what it is. If you've got errors like that you need to fix them.